# Is there an exclusive OR operator in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

This is my statement

```
IF (@UserName IS NULL AND @EditorKey IS NULL) OR (@UserName IS NOT NULL AND @EditorKey IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('One of @UserName, @EditorKey must be non-null.', 15, 0)
    RETURN
END
```

What I want is to be able to do something like this:

```
IF (@UserName IS NOT NULL) XOR (@EditorKey IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('One of @UserName, @EditorKey must be non-null.', 15, 0)
    RETURN
END
```

For two parameters it isn't that big of a deal, but some procs have three or four where in only one may be passed and the rest should be null.

Comment: Your first statement, `(a AND b) OR (NOT a AND NOT b)`, is a replacement for `a EQU b` (logical equivalence), which is logically the negation of `XOR`. The latter is represented, for example, like this: `(a AND NOT b) OR (NOT a AND b)` or like this: `(a OR b) AND (NOT a OR NOT b)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL XOR Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411619/t-sql-xor-operator)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not very succinct, but you could expand out the logic like this:

```
WHERE
    (NOT ((@UserName IS NOT NULL) AND (@EditorKey IS NOT NULL))) AND
    ((@UserName IS NOT NULL) OR (@EditorKey IS NOT NULL))
```

Or use the bitwise XOR operator (^):

```
WHERE
    (CASE WHEN (@UserName IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ^
    (CASE WHEN (@EditorKey IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

You can use a similar approach where there are three or four parameters, and exactly one must have a value:

```
WHERE
    (CASE WHEN (@Var1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN (@Var2 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN (@Var3 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN (@Var4 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: The first half of the expression is essentially `((@UserName IS NULL) OR (@EditorKey IS NULL))`, according to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: @Andriy Agreed, I'm treating `(@UserName IS NOT NULL)` as a general case boolean expression without simplifying any of the logic.

Comment: It isn't pretty, but at least it will scale.

Comment: It's slightly unsatisfying if there isn't a better way to do it.  The main limitation seems to be the lack of a proper bool data type in TSQL.

Answer (score 1):

As a cheat, you can do:

```
If @UserName+@EditorKey is null and coalesce(@UserName,@EditorKey) is not null
```

It's shorter, but that may be the only thing it has going for it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bitwise XOR, but it's not necessarily what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx

In your particular case, I find it more immediate to rewrite it like so:

```
IF (@UserName IS NULL) = (@EditorKey IS NULL) BEGIN
```

Comment: Love it. To morph this into true XOR, `((logical condition) <> (other logical condition))`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you the SQL server Boolean data type is not comparable? "IF (NULL IS NULL) = (NULL IS NULL) PRINT 'COMPARABLE'" yields "Incorrect syntax near '='"

Comment: @shannon: Shouldn't you be wrapping that print in between begin/end?

Comment: @Denis: It's surely better form but not necessary for single operations. The result is the same. Can you give it a try and tell me if I'm wrong? I'm writing similar constraints at this very moment. Would love to use this technique and upvote you.

Comment: Tbh, I merely translated what I do Postgres, where it works just fine... I occasionally use the construct in check constraints to make fields mutually exclusive.