# Conditional null constraint on Null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following `SQL` table:

```
create table dbo.[File]
(
  Id int identity not null
    constraint PK_File_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  MimeType nvarchar (400) not null,
  Name nvarchar (80) null,
  Slug nvarchar (80) null
)
```

How can I create a constraint that allows `Name` and `Slug` to be both `null` but never only one of them. So when `Name` or `Slug` is not `null` the other must also be not `null`.

Comment: basically set a constraint on `(name is null) xor (slug is null)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411619/t-sql-xor-operator

Comment: Are you sure MS SQL Server supports xor? I tried and does not seem to support it.

Comment: that's why I linked on how to do xor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [check constraint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[File] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_File__Name_Slug 
    CHECK ((Slug IS NULL AND Name IS NULL) OR (Name IS NOT NULL AND Slug IS NOT NULL));

-- TESTS
INSERT dbo.[File] (MimeType, Name, Slug) VALUES ('X', NULL, 'X'); -- FAIL 
INSERT dbo.[File] (MimeType, Name, Slug) VALUES ('X', 'X', 'X');
INSERT dbo.[File] (MimeType, Name, Slug) VALUES ('X', 'X', NULL); -- FAIL 
INSERT dbo.[File] (MimeType, Name, Slug) VALUES ('X', NULL, NULL);
```

---

**EDIT**

*(My comment was too long...)*

I don't think there is a shorter way, and even if there were it would only be syntactic sugar, logically the same check would be performed.

If the real example is a lot more columns and you are really worried about the cost of checking all the columns, then create an extension table, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[FileExendedProperties] 
(
        FileID INT NOT NULL,
        Name NVARCHAR (80) NOT NULL,
        Slug NVARCHAR (80) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FileExendedProperties__FileID PRIMARY KEY (FileID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FileExendedProperties__FileID FOREIGN KEY (FileID) 
        REFERENCES dbo.[File] (FileID)
);
```

Since the columns in your extension table are not nullable, they must either all be not null, or there not be a record in there at all, e.g. all columns will be null.

Comment: Yes, that was what I ended up using ... I wasn't sure if there was a shortest option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at check constraints. Please see documentation below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187550.aspx

Comment: Yes, I was doing a check constraint ... But how to do that with a check constaint? Usually I use it to restrict a column to certain values and not for null with another column