# XOR in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have to display the countries that are big by area or big by population but not both and Show name, population and area. Basically it's a XOR operation if i am not wrong.

A country is big if it has an area of more than 3 million sq km or it has a population of more than 250 million.

I have tried this

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world
WHERE (area > 30000000 | population > 25000000) &
      (area < 30000000 & population < 25000000)
```

I am trying this on [sqlzoo.net - SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial: Q.No-8](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial#One_or_the_other_.28but_not_both.29). Please select the SQL Engine to SQLSERVER.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14731578/4832634

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL XOR Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411619/t-sql-xor-operator)

Comment: @shA.t No I guess not.

Comment: @Pawel Lukasik, I had referred to this post before attempting, I agre this does explain the logic I am finding it difficult to implement as ^ (CARET) does not work with SQLServer, if i am not wrong.

Comment: @Ashish you should not use the caret (^) as this is bitwise xor operator. You should use the other answer from that post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can implement a XOR like this - don't forget that the question will require you to use <= to correctly use the XOR operator:

```
SELECT name
    , population
    , area
FROM world
WHERE (area > 3000000 AND population <= 250000000)
OR (area <= 3000000 AND population > 250000000)
```

Comment: This query has a problem.  It will ignore areas which match exactly 3 million km^2 or populations with exactly 2.5 million.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I merely edited the logic in the `OP's` example to get the `XOR` logic, which is why I left the area and population comparison as in the original post (`area > 30000000 | population > 25000000`).

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu, Thanks for the suggestion but it does not produce the required table.

Comment: @Ashish Why is that? Can you post some sample data and expected results? Also, can you explain on the test data why it isn't returning the correct data?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, I have tried multiple things but none are working, the link to this question is here http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial , Q No 8,kindly select the SQLEngine to SQL Server before attempting.

Comment: @Ashish Just to point out, you are comparing with the wrong numbers (and **my mistake** for copy-pasting them from your question into my answer instead of writing them myself). Your conditions are comparing the area with `30.000.000` (not 3 million) and the population with `25.000.000` (not 250 million), so you're missing and adding some zeros. Just use this query and you'll get the "happy face" on sqlzoo.

Comment: Thanks @Radu, my bad, will look closer at nos in future.An important lesson indeed.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT name,
   population,
   area
FROM world
WHERE (area > 3000000 XOR population > 250000000)
```

The question wants you to answer like this. This is the correct and short way of using 'XOR' for this question.

Comment: In MS SQL the XOR keyword did not parse.
However the "^" symbol worked like a charm, but I am using it for bitwise logic, which is a little different from the question that was asked. 

But since (area > 3000000) will resolve to a boolean, the ^ should still work.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT name,
       population,
       area
FROM world
WHERE (area > 3000000 AND population <= 25000000) OR   -- big area, small population
      (area <= 3000000 AND population > 25000000)      -- small area, big population
```

Note that I used `<=` to represent the "smaller then" condition.  This is to avoid a situation where an area equals 3 million km^2 or a population exactly equals 2.5 million.  Using `<` would eliminate data in this case.

Comment: I agree with your `<=` edit, although just pointing out that the question says "**more** than 3 million sq km or it has a population of **more** than 250 million", which would imply a non-inclusive comparison.

Comment: Also, the OP's post has a non-inclusive comparison operator. (`area > 30000000 | population > 25000000`)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT name,
       population,
       area
  FROM world
 WHERE (area > 3000000) <> /* XOR */ (population > 25000000)
```

Is briefer albeit less readable.
As a general rule, `<>` or `!=` is a good replacement for logicial `XOR`.

Comment: SQL Server does not support comparing two boolean expressions. You cannot do "(a > b) <> (c > d)", must do "((a > b) and (c <= d)) or ((a <= b) and (c > d))" instead.

Comment: IIF(area > 3000000, 1, 0) <> IIF(population > 25000000)

Comment: Bear in mind that **IIF** function is only supported on **SQL Server 2012** and later

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world
WHERE (area > 3000000 OR population > 250000000) AND NOT 
      (area > 3000000 AND population > 250000000)
```

Imagine this through a Venn diagram where a = area > 3000000, b = population > 250000000

a XOR b would be equal to (a Union b) Minus (a Intersection b)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NAME,
       population,
       area
FROM   world
WHERE  area > 3000000
        OR population > 250000000
EXCEPT
SELECT NAME,
       population,
       area
FROM   world
WHERE  area > 3000000
       AND population > 250000000
```

Above is the actual representation in set theory.

Comment: Why hasn't this been the acceptable answer and scored a point at least!?!?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name, population, area
from world
where (population >= 250000000 AND NOT area >= 3000000) OR 
      (area >= 3000000 AND NOT population >= 250000000);
```

This will sure give you your desire answer.

Answer (score -1):

The query will be like this:

```
SELECT name, population, area 
FROM world
WHERE (area > 3000000 AND  population < 250000000) OR
      (area < 3000000 AND  population > 250000000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select name, population, area
from world
where area>3000000 xor population > 250000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: The same approach has already been shown by Volkan.