# Left Join Table with Exclusive OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Is there a way to join 2 tables together on one and only one of the possible conditions? Joining on condition "a" or "b" could duplicate rows, but I'm looking to only join once. I came up with a potential solution, but I'm wondering if there is a more slick way to do it.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.col1 = b.col1
    OR (a.col1 != b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2)
```

This would join the tables on col1 OR col2 BUT NOT BOTH. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: show sample data and desired result...

Comment: if it works for you (returns expected results) then I'd stick with it because when you read this code a year from now, you'll have a better chance of understanding it. Remember, the optimizer can rewrite your query a different way to get the same results. So if "slick" is what it looks like and isn't performance driven, I'm not sure there is a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL XOR Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411619/t-sql-xor-operator)

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: This is not clear. It is also strangely phrased--per some odd mental model. You have 1 join. What do do "on one and only one of the possible conditions", "could duplicate rows" & "looking to only join once" mean? Your test means `a.col1 = b.col1 OR a.col2 = b.col2`--simpler. What does "on col1 OR col2 BUT NOT BOTH" mean? You mean, exactly 1 equality? That's `a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 <> b.col2 OR a.col1 <> b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2`. If you want to learn about coding for performance, read everything in the manual re indexes & optimization. And there are books free online in pdf. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not more efficient but I think more clear

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
  ON     (a.col1 = b.col1 or  a.col2 = b.col2)
 AND NOT (a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2)
```

Comment: `AND !(expression)` isn't valid SQL Server Syntax. It would need to be `AND NOT(expression)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method works.  If you only want one (or a handful) of columns from `b`, I would suggest:

```
SELECT a.*, COALESCE(b.col3, b2.col3)
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.col1 = b.col1 LEFT JOIN
     TableB b2
     ON a.col1 <> b2.col1 AND a.col2 = b2.col2;
```

Removing the `OR` from the `JOIN` conditions allows the optimizer to generate a better execution plan.