# Xor between two conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause, window-functions

There are `OR` and `AND` operators in T-SQL. `AND` means when two conditions are true and `OR` means if only first condition is true, if only second condition is true or if both conditions are true.

But I need something like `XOR` which is like `OR` but if both are true, the `WHERE` condition is not applied.

Example :

```
select * 
from [Table] 
where Id in (@FromId) XOR TypeId = @TypeId
```

My question is: how should I write this query so if `Id in (@FromId)` found, it doesn't check `TypeId =@TypeId` and if `Id in (@FromId)` isn't found, it checks for `TypeId =@TypeId` .

I know that I can write this for solving the problem :

```
select * from [Table] where Id in (@FromId) 
if @@ROWCOUNT =0
select * from  [Table] where TypeId =@TypeId
```

but I want write it in one query, for simplicity, performance, less code ,....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those queries are not logically identical.

Comment: what does it mean exactly? can you explain more?

Comment: Add table DDL sample data and desired results and you'll probably see.

Comment: so is there any solution to this kind of problem or not? I cant write this kind of  queries in one query?

Comment: It's a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411619/t-sql-xor-operator)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have read it before and i Think my question is in this rules. I check this two links from you two dears but i couldnt find my answer. maybe i have to more google

Comment: If you've read it, I think you should read it again. Minimal reproducible example for SQL queries: Show us `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements with enough sample data to cover all of your use cases (a row that meets one criteria, a row that meets the other, a row that meets both, and a row that meets neither), then show us that the result should be in each case.

Comment: My understanding of what you're asking changed as I re-read your question. You're saying that you want to run the second query if-and-only-if the first returns ZERO results. If the first query returns even a single row, you don't want to evaluate the second expression. Yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically an XOR can be expressed in terms of AND and OR as follows:

```
 (cond1 AND NOT cond2) OR (NOT cond1 AND cond2)
```

So your query can be written as

```
select * 
from [Table] 
where (Id in (@FromId) AND TypeId <> @TypeId) OR (Id NOT IN (@FromId) AND TypeId = @TypeId)
```

Answer (score 1):

XOR in sql server is ^.  Please give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I'm not crazy about this, but...

```
if exists(select * from [Table] where Id in (@FromId)) begin
    select * from [Table] where Id in (@FromId)
end
else begin
    select * from [Table] where TypeId = @TypeId
end
```

Is @FromId a CSV or other iterable entity? I would transform it into a table and join, as opposed to using the IN operator and suffering a performance hit.

Comment: Thank you for reply . but I think my code which is in question body is better because in your code we have 3 select in worst situtation but in my code only two.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*, max(case when id in (@FromId) then 1 else 0 end) has_from_id
    from mytable t
) t
where id in (@FromId) or (has_from_id = 0 and typeId = @typeId)
```

Another typical approach is `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where id in (@FromId)
union all
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    typeId = @typeId
    and not exists (select 1 from mytable where id in (@FromId))
```

Comment: Thank you but what about performance???  I need simplicity, performance, less code

Comment: I found this answer the most comprehensible of the ones I read across SO, personally. Thanks. The performance should be decent for either of these, they're trivial for even the most obtuse query planner to optimize.